# Missing functions in libboost_thread?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

Continuing to try to solve my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928719/undefined-reference-to-boostthread-functions-when-building-caffe) I am trying to figure out where the `join`, `start_thread` and `~thread` are supposed to come from but I can't see they exist at all in the `libboost_thread` library (this is version 1.64.0 that I build and installed from the sources), for example, checking if the `join` function exists:

```
$ nm --demangle /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so | grep join
             U pthread_join@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000011e00 T boost::thread::join_noexcept()
0000000000011f90 T boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(timespec const&, bool&)
0000000000010dc0 T boost::thread::joinable() const
```

I can see that there is an undefined symbol `pthread_join` but my understanding is that there's supposed to be a separate `join` function inside the `libboost_thread` library itself.

I checked several different versions installed on another Ubuntu 14.04 machine of ours and got pretty much the same results:

```
$ nm --demangle /usr/local/boost-1.60.0/lib/libboost_thread.so | grep join
                 U pthread_join@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000012070 T boost::thread::join_noexcept()
0000000000012200 T boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(timespec const&, bool&)
0000000000010ed0 T boost::thread::joinable() const
$ nm --demangle /home/ubuntu/src/anaconda2/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.61.0 | grep join
                 U pthread_join@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000014140 T boost::thread::join_noexcept()
00000000000144e0 T boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(timespec const&, bool&)
0000000000010870 T boost::thread::joinable() const
$ nm --demangle /home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.61.0 | grep join
                 U pthread_join@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000014140 T boost::thread::join_noexcept()
00000000000144e0 T boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(timespec const&, bool&)
0000000000010870 T boost::thread::joinable() const
```

Comment: Hmm, something looks wrong. I have join, join_noexcept, and joinable (as well as do_try_join_* variants)

Comment: Thanks @AndyG I check several versions on another Ubuntu 14.04 machine but got the same results (updated above). Could you post the output of `nm --demangle /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so | grep join` in a response? It would help me alot.

Comment: I'm not on a Ubuntu machine, and my initial comment was for a windows boost DLL. However, on my Linux box, I also have the same three functions you mention. Looking into it, the `boost::thread::join` is declared `inline`, so it is likely that the compiler used to build for Linux is able to `inline` the function effectively, but not the one for Windows.